# Editing members of an object in an ObservableCollection through SelectedItem in a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

this is my first project in WPF and I am currently stuck on my Shopping Cart.
I create an object `newbasketItem` with the member `ItemQuantity` with the value "1". My listview works perfectly fine through Binding. I can add items, remove items and clear my Collection. Now to my problem:
I want to select an item in my viewlist and increment the ItemQuantity with a button.

Is there any way to edit the `ItemQuantity`when it has already been added to the Collection?

```
BasketItem newBasketItem = new BasketItem();
newBasketItem.ItemQuantity = 1;

basketitems.Add(newBasketItem);
```

newBasketItem is my ObservableCollection.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BasketItem` class should implement the `INotifiedPropertyChange` interface and the listview content will be automatically updated (provided you have a binding on `ItemQuantity`).

For example:

```
public class BasketItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int quantity = 0;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public int ItemQuantity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.quantity;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.quantity)
            {
                this.quantity = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `ObservableCollection` already implements this interface but it is not enough since it only allows to trigger event when items are added, deleted or moved. But if you want the UI to be notified when an item is modified, this item must also implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

---

About your click event, you should use an `ICommand` as suggested by @Sir Rufo. You can also do the following with a XAML like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" Margin="0,50,0,0" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemQuantity}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and in your code behind:

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.ClickedItem as BasketItem;
    item.ItemQuantity++;
}
```

Comment: Hi Arnaud, thank you very much for your reply.
The code is working but I don't know the syntax to put in my click event to increase the quantity by 1. I want to select the item in my listview.

Comment: The event for items add, delete, move is defined in INotifyCollectionChanged. ObservableCollection implements both INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyProperyChanged but only for the collection itself

Comment: @MikeSharp Forget about the click event handler. Define an ICommand property in BasketItem and name it IncreaseQuantity and bind that to the Command property of your button. There are a lot of examples how to create and bind an ICommand

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, Arnaud and Rufo.
I got it to work now with the following code:

private void BTN_QuantityUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = Listview1.SelectedItem as BasketItem;
            item.ItemQuantity++;
        }

But I will definetely look into ICommand since I feel like my solution is pretty amateur like :)